# Aonde está meu erro?

Tags: java, android, interface, imageview

Estou fazendo um joguinho em *Android* bem simples, mas estou tendo problemas com a interface.

Criei a interface em xml, e setei a classe java correspondente a ela (setContentView...), até ai ok. Porém quero que na hora em que essa *Activity* é chamada, sejam setadas algumas imagens.
 Através do onCreate eu consegui setar essa *ImageViews*, ai resolvi criar métodos que fizessem isso, e apenas chama-los dentro do onCreate, mas a partir dai começa o problema, essa Activity fica totalmente preta.

Aqui estão os as partes do código. 
Código Activity a ser aberta

```
public class Jogo extends AppCompatActivity {
//ImageViews que conterão as imagens relacionadas aos valores
ImageView imgView1;
ImageView imgView2;
ImageView imgView3;
ImageView imgView4;
ImageView imgView5;
ImageView imgView6;
ImageView imgView7;
ImageView imgView8;
ImageView imgView9;

//ImageViews de Iguais e Mais
ImageView maisView1;
ImageView maisView2;
ImageView maisView3;
ImageView maisView4;
ImageView maisView5;
ImageView maisView6;


//Iguais
ImageView igualView1;
ImageView igualView2;
ImageView igualView3;


//========================================================================//
//BOTÃO
Button btEnvia;
//EDIT TEXT
EditText editResposta;

//========================================================================//
Problema problema = new Problema();
//

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_jogo);







}



//Cria ImageViews e linka com os do Layout.
private void criaImgView (){

   //ImageViews que conterão as imagens relacionadas aos valores
    imgView1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView1);
    imgView2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView2);
    imgView3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView3);
    imgView4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView4);
    imgView5 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView5);
    imgView6 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView6);
    imgView7 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView7);
    imgView8 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView8);
    imgView9 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView9);

    //Operadores matemáticos
    maisView1= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.maisView1);
    maisView2= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.maisView2);
    maisView3= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.maisView3);
    maisView4= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.maisView4);
    maisView5= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.maisView5);
    maisView6= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.maisView6);

    //IGUAL
    igualView1= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.igualView1);
    igualView2= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.igualView2);
    igualView3= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.igualView3);


}

//Cria instancias dos elementos do layout.
private void intanciaObj (){

    btEnvia = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btEntra);

    editResposta = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editResposta);

}

//Seta ImageViews
private void imageViews (){


    imgView1.setImageResource(problema.arFinal[0][0]);
    imgView2.setImageResource(problema.arFinal[0][0]);
    imgView3.setImageResource(problema.arFinal[0][0]);

    imgView4.setImageResource(problema.arFinal[1][0]);
    imgView5.setImageResource(problema.arFinal[1][0]);
    imgView6.setImageResource(problema.arFinal[0][0]);

    imgView7.setImageResource(problema.arFinal[2][0]);
    imgView8.setImageResource(problema.arFinal[1][0]);
    imgView9.setImageResource(problema.arFinal[0][0]);

}

private void preparaTudo(){

    criaImgView();
    intanciaObj();
    imageViews();

}
```

Aqui o código da classe, onde monto previamente algumas variáveis usadas para definir valores a serem aplicados na Activity Jogo (tentei primeiro instanciando a classe problema na Activity Jogo, e depois colocando todos os métodos da classe Problema direto na Activity, mas continuou com o mesmo resultado )

```
public class Problema {

//**VARIAVEIS RELACIONADAS A PARTE DOS VALORES DO PROBLEMA**

//=============================================================================================//
//MATRIZ PROBLEMA (VALORES)
int[][] matrizProblema = new int[3][4];
//array com os 3 valores
int[] arrayVal = new int[3];
//variavel define valor maximo numeros
int limite ;
//============================================================================================//
ArrayList<Icon> ico = new ArrayList<Icon>();

//**VÁRIAVEIS RELACIONADAS AS IMAGENS**
//============================================================================================//
//Array para guardar os caminhos das imagens
int[][] arrayImg =new int[3][2];
//Array que guarda os indices das imagens a serem usadas
int[] valoresImg = new int[3];
//Numero max de imagens no projeto
int numMaxImg = 3;
//Array final das imagens
int[][] arFinal = new int[3][2];
//============================================================================================//
public Problema (){

    montaMatriz();
    preparaImg();

}

//**PARTE RELACIONADA AOS VALORES.**
//============================================================================================//

//SORTEIA OS VALORES DO PROBLEM
private void sorteiaValor() {

    do {

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

            arrayVal[i] = (int) (Math.random()*limite);
        }

    }
    while (arrayVal[0] == arrayVal[1] || arrayVal[0] == arrayVal[2] || arrayVal[1] == arrayVal[2]);
}

//MONTA MATRIZ
private void montaMatriz () {
    sorteiaValor();
    montaPrimeiraLinha();
    montaSegundaLinha();
    montaTerceiraLinha();

}
private void montaPrimeiraLinha(){
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
        matrizProblema[0][i]= arrayVal[0];
    }
    matrizProblema[0][4]= arrayVal[0]*3;
}
private void montaSegundaLinha(){

    for(int i=0; i<2;i++){
        matrizProblema[1][i]= arrayVal[1];

    }
    matrizProblema[1][2]= arrayVal[0];

    matrizProblema[1][3]= matrizProblema[1][0]+ matrizProblema[1][1]+matrizProblema[1][2];
}
private void montaTerceiraLinha(){
    for(int i = 0 ; i<3;i++){
        matrizProblema[2][i]= arrayVal[i];
    }
    matrizProblema[2][3]= matrizProblema[2][0]+matrizProblema[2][1]+matrizProblema[2][2];    }

//============================================================================================//

//**PARTE RELACIONADA AS IMAGENS.**
//============================================================================================//
//Chama todos os metodos relacionados nas imagens
private void preparaImg(){

    preencheImgs();
    sorteiaValorImgs();
    escolheImgs();
}

//Serve para preencher um array com as refêrencias das imagens

private void preencheImgs (){

    arrayImg[0][0] = R.drawable.caveira1;
    arrayImg[0][1] = R.drawable.caveira2;

    arrayImg[1][0] = R.drawable.download1;
    arrayImg[1][1] = R.drawable.download2;

    arrayImg[2][0] = R.drawable.menos1;
    arrayImg[2][1] = R.drawable.menos2;

}

//Sorteia valores para decidir qual imagem será relacionada com cada valor.
private void sorteiaValorImgs() {

    do {

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

            valoresImg[i] = (int) (Math.random()*numMaxImg);
        }

    }
    while (valoresImg[0] == valoresImg[1] || valoresImg[0] == valoresImg[2] || valoresImg[1] == valoresImg[2]);
    }

//Monta um array, utilizando o array com os caminhos das imagens e o array com indices sorteados das imagens
private void escolheImgs(){

    for (int i =0;i< valoresImg.length;i++ ){
        int temp = valoresImg[i]-1;
        for (int j=0; i<2;i++ ) {
            switch (valoresImg[i]) {
                case 1:
                    arFinal[i][j] = arrayImg[temp][j];
            }
        }
    }

}}
```

Erro retornado:

```
10-18 22:12:14.815 30508-30508/com.belialgames.rachakuka E/Trace: error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
10-18 22:12:15.147 30508-30508/com.belialgames.rachakuka E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable', referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.hasOverlappingRendering
10-18 22:12:15.649 30508-30508/com.belialgames.rachakuka E/MMUMapper: fail to register MVA, unsupported format(0x5)
10-18 22:12:15.796 30508-30508/com.belialgames.rachakuka E/MMUMapper: fail to register MVA, unsupported format(0x5)
10-18 22:12:21.347 30508-30508/com.belialgames.rachakuka E/MMUMapper: fail to register MVA, unsupported format(0x5)
```

Comment: Muito complicado achar o erro é muito código, dá um breakpoint e teste a aplicação em modo debug!

Comment: O `onCreate` não tem código! Como é que era suposto acontecer alguma coisa ?

Comment: Desculpe a ignorância, eu pretendia usar o onCreate para definir as imagens que vão ficar nas ImageViews.
Como posso definir essas imagens sem ser no onCreate?

Comment: O que quer que seja que é para acontecer quando uma Activity abre tem de estar no `onCreate` direta ou indiretamente. Se explicar melhor o que está exatamente a tentar fazer fica mais fácil de ajudar.

Comment: Entendi o que disse, acabei apagando os métodos que estava chamando dentro de onCreate pois vi que eram uma parte da causa do bug.

Comment: O que quis dizer com indiretamente?
Talvez seja o que preciso, consigo setar as imagens usando o onCreate, mas uma por uma, o que visualmente não me agrada, tentei usar métodos dentro dele, mas acho que ai começa o meu problema.

Comment: Diretamente -> chamar `setImageResource` no `onCreate`. Indiretamente -> chamar no `onCreate` o método `A` que por sua vez chama o método `B` que chama os  `setImageResource`s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Que eu saiba você deve instanciar as views no método `OnCreate()` já que ele que está com o layout do `xml`, tente colocar todos os `findViewById` no `OnCreate()` (pode deixar declarado fora como está, assim outros métodos também podem usar eles), a tela deve estar completamente preta pois você instanciou errado seus views, logo, não da pra igualar eles a imagem alguma. Você também não chama seu método `preparaTudo()` então mesmo que tivesse tudo certo acho que a tela continuaria preta (Programo em `Xamarin.Android`, mas a lógica é a mesma pelo que sei, inclusive só de colocar fora do método ele já aponta um erro).

Comment: Realmente, postei o código sem o preparaTudo(), tirei ele antes pois vi que tinha algo a ver com o erro.
Deixa eu fazer uma pergunta, essa Activity que estou chamando, depende de algumas configurações, portanto fiz criei o layout dela em xml, e nesse momento que eu a chamo, quero que sejam colocadas nela, certas imagens e valores, substituindo esses valores default do layout.

Está certo meu raciocínio ou tem alguma maneira melhor de fazer isso?

Comment: Não entendi direito o que quis dizer, você está perguntando se é melhor setar a imagem pelo `XML` ou pelo código `Java`? Se for isso acho que tanto faz, mas do jeito que você está fazendo também é possível, você só precisa colocar todos aqueles "`findViewById`" dentro do método `OnCreate()` pra instanciar eles corretamente. Depois você chama o `imageViews()` pra setar alguma imagem para as imageviews. Também está faltando o evento ao clicar no Botão (que acho eu que seria chamar algum dos métodos da classe `Problema`), mas acho que isso você vai fazer depois

Comment: Respondendo o que você disse ali acima ("consigo setar as imagens usando o onCreate, mas uma por uma, o que visualmente não me agrada, tentei usar métodos dentro dele, mas acho que ai começa o meu problema."), você pode setar essas imagens em um método como está atualmente, o problema é instanciar elas fora do `OnCreate`, você tem que declarar as variaveis fora dele (para poder usar de fora, já que ele é `protected`) e instanciar elas dentro dele, daí pra frente você pode setar as imagens em outros métodos e etc

Comment: Minha duvida é: Eu preciso colocar esses valores default para só muda-los no onCreate, ou tem algum meio de já abrir o layout com os valores e imagens que quero? não tendo assim que defini-los no onCreate.
PS: poderia apenas seta-los no xml, mas preciso ainda decidir através de alguns métodos, quais imagens e valores irei usar.

Comment: Entendo, obrigado pela atenção e ajuda.

Comment: Você pode setar eles pelo XML com o `android:src="@drawable/nome da imagem"` (não tinha visto o PS), como também pode setar eles por outro método como está fazendo, o problema (que eu saiba) é só o `findViewById` fora do `OnCreate()`, já que ele tem que ficar dentro. A propósito se a dúvida foi resolvida marca o V ali em baixo da minha resposta pra ajudar pessoas com dúvidas parecidas e me ajudar também haha. Tente colocar esses `findViewById` dentro do `OnCreate()` e depois chama o `imageViews()` pra setar as imagens do mesmo jeitinho que está pra ver se dá certo

Comment: Indiretamente, você me deu a resposta que precisava, VLW.